# How do I make the text hover over a data point?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

When I hover over the data point it keeps the information for that data point locked in the left portion of the screen. How do I get it to be where the users mouse is? Here's what I have

`````
            var tooltip = d3.select("body")
                .append("div")
                .attr("id", "tooltip")
                .attr("style", "position: absolute; opacity: 0;")
                .style("border", "solid")
                .style("border-width", "1px")
                .style("border-radius", "5px")
                .style("padding", "10px");````
        ...

            .on("mouseover", function(d){
                        d3.select("#tooltip")
                            .transition()
                            .duration(200)
                            .style("opacity", .9)
                            .text("User: " + d.user + " " +
                                "Top Artist: " + " " + d.artist + " " + 
                                "Top Song: " + d.track)
                        d3.select(this)
                            .transition()
                            .duration(100)
                            .attr("r", 23)
                            .attr("fill", "orange");
                        })
                        .on("mouseout", function(d) {
                            d3.select("#tooltip")
                              .style("opacity", 0)
                            d3.select(this)
                              .transition()
                              .duration(100)
                              .attr("r", 15)
                              .attr("fill", "black");
                        });
`````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `d3.event.pageX` and `d3.event.pageY` built into D3. When you're adding your tooltip, try this:

```
d3.select("#tooltip")
    .transition()
    .duration(200)
    .style("opacity", .9)
    .text("User: " + d.user + " " +
        "Top Artist: " + " " + d.artist + " " + 
        "Top Song: " + d.track)
    .style("left", d3.event.pageX + "px")
    .style("top", d3.event.pageY - 28 + "px");
```

You may need to adjust the `top` style based on the height of your tooltip.